# How to get wifi router's ssid using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

i am developing an android mobile app using phonegap and java. My requirement is to capture wifi router's ssid and store it to database.

Is there anyway to capture **ssid**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to develop a plugin for that.

Comment: Is it not possible using Cordova plugin?

Comment: I tried wifi mac address and got success..

Comment: I got success man..i got my wifi ssid..like "MyNetwork Name"

Comment: @Aravin, could you provide me any link regarding this?

Comment: i will post here..for android..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following(for android only). Include the following class into your `src` folder

WifiInfoPlugin.class:

```
package com.example.getmac;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class WifiInfoPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final String SSID_NAME = "WifiInfo";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (SSID_NAME.equals(action)) {
            String wifiInfo = this.getWifiInfo();
            Log.e("Wifi SSID", wifiInfo);
            if(wifiInfo != ""){
                JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
            try {
                    jsonResult.put("Wifi SSID", wifiInfo);
                    PluginResult r= new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,jsonResult);
                    callbackContext.success(wifiInfo);
                    r.setKeepCallback(true);
                    return true;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
                callbackContext.error("error");
                r.setKeepCallback(true);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);
                return true;
            }
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String getWifiInfo() {

        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
        //String address = info.getMacAddress();
        String address = info.getSSID ();
        Log.e("ssid address", address);
        return address;
    }

}
```

after that in your index.html script is like:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady(){
     var success = function(result) { alert("The SSID is " + result); };
     var error = function(message) { alert("Oopsie! " + message); };
     WifiInfo.createEvent(success,error);
}
```

then create getWifiInfoFromPLT.js is like include this js in index page

```
var WifiInfo = {

createEvent : function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'WifiInfoPlugin',
            'WifiInfo', []);
}
};
```

Add the below in your `res/xml/cofig.xml` folder

```
 <feature name="WifiInfoPlugin" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="com.example.getWifiInfo.WifiInfoPlugin" >
    </param>
</feature>
```

and add the `necessary permissons in your manifest`. Let me know any difficulties

Sample Output:
[image]